# Looking for explanation about shader model 3.0 and 4.0

Tags: shader

I'm trying to understand what a shader model is. I understand what a shader is, and what GLSL and HLSL are.

But what is a shader model ver. 3.0 and 4.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLSL is OpenGL's high level shading language, HLSL is Direct3D's. Shader model 3.0 and 4.0 refer to the Direct3D shader model. Wikipedia has good explanations, and summary of the version differences.
What shader model is supported on a system mainly depends on the GPU hardware. (But for shader model 4.0 under Direct3D at least DirectX 10 or newer is required, which requires at least Windows Vista.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_shader_language
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glsl

Comment: Is there any analogous phrase in GLSL for shader model?